# Nativescript using android

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am new to NativeScript. 
I am trying to figure out how to use the Bluetooth Native Api (Classic not LE). 
I have a hard time finding out how I can interact with the bluetooth api.

The first wall I hit is using android in my typescript code.

For exemple in a component if i do  :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.info(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)
}
```

I get the error:

JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'os' of undefined

Any suggestions ?

Comment: This might sound stupid, but, there goes - did you run the sample on an Android device?

Comment: Since you are using typescript and i'm guessing you didn't add the platform declarations you should add `declare const android:any;` to the top of your file or you can set `"noEmitOnError": false` in the tsconfig.json

Comment: None of those solutions work. @OseiFortune with you proposition i error : os of undefined

Comment: Are you importing android from 'application' if so remove it and do @Nick Iliev suggested below. android class from application is not the same as android that is global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have access (and intelliSense which is even better) via TypeScript to the native APIs you need the generated declarations files. Fortunately, you do not have to provide these files as they are already avaiable via the [tns-platform-declarations plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations)

To install the declarations do the fiollwing in your Angular project

```
npm i tns-platform-declarations --save-dev
```

And then create references.d.ts file with the following content:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

Finally, modify the content of your **tsconfig.json** file to include the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

If for some reason you do not need IntelliSense you can skip all this and simply give a type to **android** in the beginning of your *.ts file

```
declare var android: any;
```

However, I would strongly recommend the first approach as it will give you really nice IntelliSense for the really enormous native APIs